# pyQT4: How to open a window from another window

Tags: window, pyqt4, qt-designer

I'm trying to open a window (QWidget) when clicking on a button. My problem is that the second window doesn't show up when I click on the button no matter what I've tried. The two windows are created using QTDesigner. 
Here is a little snippet explaining what I'm trying to do:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from win1 import *
from win2 import *
import sys

class win1(QWidget, Ui_Win1):
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    self.parent = parent
    QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(parent)
    self.connect(self.pushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.on_btn_clicked)

  def on_btn_clicked(self):
    self.child = win2(self.parent)
    self.child.show()

class win2(QWidget, Ui_Win2):
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(parent)

def main(args):
  app = QApplication(args)
  win = QWidget()
  a = win1(win)
  win.show()
  result = app.exec_()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

What am I missing here ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but two random thoughts:

If you add a print statement to `on_btn_clicked`, do you see anything when you click on the button? This would diagnose whether it's an event triggering issue

Does it work if you change the `setupUI(parent)` commands to `setupUI(self)`?